# Sending bitmap image to next activity in android and converting it into string

Tags: android, android-intent, bitmap

I m not able to convert the bitmap into string and pass it to the JSON  by send the intent.putExtra.....And on receiving it on Create method of next activity....
The Default is giving error and i have jpeg images ...
How to fix this problem....

```
Intent   Intent inn=getIntent()
bitmap = (Bitmap) inn.getParcelableExtra("bmp_img");
ByteArrayOutputStream baos=new  ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100, baos);
        byte [] b=baos.toByteArray();
        String temp=Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Comment: Are you sure that you need to pass images through the intent? It is slow and won't work for large images...

Answer (score 0):

```
public String imageCompression(String image) {
        // to compress image
        BitmapFactory.Options bmpFactoryOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(image, bmpFactoryOptions);
        Bitmap out = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, 300, 300, false);

        String[] bits = image.split("/");
        String lastOne = bits[bits.length - 1];
        File imageFile = null;
        File imagesFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                "CompressedImages");

        if (imagesFolder.isDirectory()) {

            imageFile = new File(imagesFolder, lastOne);
            FileOutputStream fOut;
            try {
                fOut = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
                out.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, fOut);
                fOut.flush();
                fOut.close();
                b.recycle();
                out.recycle();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } else {
            imagesFolder.mkdirs();
            imageFile = new File(imagesFolder, lastOne);
            FileOutputStream fOut;
            try {
                fOut = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
                out.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fOut);
                fOut.flush();
                fOut.close();
                b.recycle();
                out.recycle();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        File file = new File(imageFile.getPath());
        byte imageData[] = new byte[(int) file.length()];
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e3) {

            e3.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e2) {

            e2.printStackTrace();
        }
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
        try {
            bis.read(imageData, 0, imageData.length);
        } catch (IOException e1) {

            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        imageDataString = Base64.encodeToString(imageData, 0);
        return imageDataString;
    }


Use this methord and for intent passing pass just as String ......
```

Answer (score 0):

i assume u are navigate from TO Activity A and B in sort of A->B

in A

```
  Uri imageUri = Uri.parse("android.resource://your.package/drawable/fileName");
  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
  intent.setType("image/png");
  intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
  startActivity(intent)
```

and in B

```
Intent intent = this.getIntent();

(Uri) getIntent().getExtras().get(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
```